# is there any alternative for AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement in asp.net core?

Tags: wcf, soap, asp.net-core, .net-core

In .net framework there is AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement, but when I am consuming encrypted SOAP service in .net core, I need to encrypt message with this class. Is there any alternative for AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement in asp.net core?

Comment: did you get any work around for this?

Comment: Just Manipulate the Respective SOPA, as this classes were not available at that moment in .net core.